# how to find the zero in terms of an unknown constant in the following expression

Tags: roots

The expression I would like to find the zero of is:
$$
-407\,x^{2} + 220275\,x - 6118.75\,ax - 15296.875\,a^{2} + 1101375\,a - 19824750
$$
I would like to express the zero in terms of $a$, I have tried doing it myself but been getting stuck. I am trying to find the zero in terms of $a$ so that I will be able to interpret the minimum of a different function for various $a$ values.

Comment: Collect the terms then it's just a quadratic equation in $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If $$k_1 x^2 + (k_2+ak_3)x+f(a)=0$$
then
$$x=\frac{-(k_2+ak_3)\pm \sqrt{(k_2+ak_3)^2 - 4k_1f(a)}}{2k_1} $$